# Git post-receive hook: “remote: Permission denied, please try again.”

Tags: git, ssh, githooks, openssh

I have a bare repository at `/home/dan/repo/` and a working copy at `/home/dan/www/project/`.
I want to have working copy automatically pull its current branch from `repo` on each commit to `repo`.

I created a file at `/home/dan/repo/hooks/post-update`:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/dan/www/project || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull

exec git-update-server-info
```

Working copy's `origin` is set to the `repo`:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = dan@server:/home/dan/repo/
```

However, on every commit I get an error:

```
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied (publickey,password).
remote: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing username from `origin` remote `url` in working copy's `.git/config` solved the issue.

#### Before:

```
url = dan@server:/home/dan/repo/
```

#### After:

```
url = /home/dan/repo/
```

Comment: You were using the `ssh` git repository address; I'm guessing you don't have public/private keypairs set to automatically login to *localhost* over `ssh` from *localhost*. Removing the `dan@server:` means git treats `repo` as a locally-stored repository, rather than accessing via `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Just curious, how do I set it up so I can login to `localhost` from `localhost`? Is it just a matter of adding `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Yep - `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ; ssh user@localhost` should work.